# Cron doesn't run sh script in ubuntu 20

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, cron

I tried different options to automatically run the backup script, it just doesn't work. Everything is fine in the logs, everything shows that the launch is in progress. What could be the problem? The script works when started manually. Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/nino_new/nino
now=$(date +"%d-%m-%y_%H:%M:%S")
filename=backups/nino_$now.json
docker exec -ti skill01 python manage.py dumpdata -o $filename -a
```

crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/nino_new/nino
* * * * * sh /root/nino_new/nino/backup.sh
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but the shebang says Bash but the crontab explicitly uses `sh`.

Comment: Possibly the issue: `-t` and `-i` may be problematic under cron, and shouldn’t be necessary anyway.

Comment: #!/bin/sh and SHELL=/bin/sh?

Comment: I have to use -ti, no way. Is there any difference in running the script manually and via cron? In terms of, can it be that the script runs fine by hand, but for some reason it does not work through cron due to the script itself?

Comment: That mismatch is not an issue. The explicit `sh` with a file whose shebang says Bash is generally a bad idea. In this case the script doesn’t have any Bashisms (yet!), so it shouldn’t cause the issue.

Comment: _Why_ do you have to use `-ti`?! One difference between running in a terminal and running under cron is that STDIN and STDOUT won’t look like TTYs in the latter (IIRC). Does it work if you remove just `-i`?

Comment: Biffen thanks a lot !!! Everything works, it looks like the problem was still in ti, I didn’t know that it must be used

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to remove the `sh` after `* * * * *` and let only the path to the script.

Comment: As outlined in comments, that would not make a difference in this particular case, because the script doesn't actually require any Bash-only functionality.